# Eclipselink is living in the past, DDL not reflecting Entities

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Weird stuff... I have happily used EclipseLink / JPA 2 as provider for my persistence unit for a while (with a MySQL RDBMS in the back). I had DDL-drop/create turned off, since I wanted to keep records in the DB and there weren't any changes to the Entities anyway.

Now I've just made some bigger changes to one Entity (adding some attributes, renaming / re-typing others, importing a previously embedded object flat into this entity, etc). I turn on DDL-drop/create, re-deploy a couple of times, and ... nothing changes!

EclipseLink actually creates (and re-creates) the SQL Tables based on the **old** information! It's like it has a copy of the Java class somewhere and ignores the one I just updated...

Even more crazy, the previously embedded object is gone. I deleted the class-file. Eclipselink **still** creates the attributes in the table of the previously embedding class.

I see no Exceptions in GlassFish server.log. I dropped and recreated the persistence Unit, no change. Any ideas? (Let me know if I should post any code / log entries, and I'll update this post.)

**Update:** After setting `eclipselink.logging.level` to `FINEST`, I still see no exceptions. The DDL-script is created (with wrong columns in it) and happily executed on the DB (creating the wrong columns of course). In the logs I see EclipseLink talking about the fields that aren't there anymore:

```
[#|2010-09-22T17:04:11.392+0200|CONFIG|glassfish3.0.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/Users/hank/NetBeansProjects/CoreServer/build/classes/_coreServerPersistenceUnit.ejb_or_metadata|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|
The alias name for the entity class [class mvs.entity.Shopper] is being defaulted to: Shopper.|#]

[#|2010-09-22T17:04:11.392+0200|CONFIG|glassfish3.0.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/Users/hank/NetBeansProjects/CoreServer/build/classes/_coreServerPersistenceUnit.ejb_or_metadata|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|
The column name for element [field msisdn] is being defaulted to: MSISDN.|#]

[#|2010-09-22T17:04:11.392+0200|CONFIG|glassfish3.0.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/Users/hank/NetBeansProjects/CoreServer/build/classes/_coreServerPersistenceUnit.ejb_or_metadata|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|
The column name for element [field imei] is being defaulted to: IMEI.|#]
```

In this case `mvs.entity.Shopper` is the class. `msisdn` is an existing field, but `imei` does not exist anymore. No idea where EclipseLink is getting the info from...

Btw, I have `eclipselink.weaving` set to `false`, since it was causing issues with lazy-loading. Could this be related?

**Update 2:** Following Gordon's advice I have looked for old copies of the entity, but couldn't find any. Deploying the appliation on a fresh GlassFish did *not* show the behaviour from above; instead the mapping was done *correctly* as was DDL-creation! Yippie :)

My only conclusion is that the old copy must be kept somewhere in GlassFish, even after undeploying... Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you enable Eclipselink logging to a file and set the logging level to debug.  Then start your application and see what messages you get about the DDL.

Comment: @Pace: thx for your response. I have updated the post. Any other idea?

Comment: You should post your latest update as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Pascal: Thx, done. But since it was my own stupid mistake, maybe I should delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a fresh copy of GlassFish and deploying the applications to it solved the problem. After comparing the two copies of GF, I found an old build artifact in `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`, which contained old entity definitions. After removing that, everything was as expected.

So at the end of the day, my own stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have an orm.xml file on your classpath with the old mappings or the Old version of the class is being deployed.  EclipseLink has no way to "store" classes between deployments.  Try decompiling the class file in your deployment to see if it has your changes.

Comment: Thank you. I decompiled the NetBeans build artifact, which was fine. Couldn't find an orm.xml file anywhere. But I managed to solve it by installing a fresh copy of glassfish 3.0.1, see update.